# Should I use pixel or cm in designing business card online?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have provided an interface to design business cards online on a web page. 
The cards should be 8.5 cm x 5.5 cm.

My problem is width and height units. Should I use pixel or centimeter in css?

In the end I want to convert it to jpg using c# `drawing class`. c# `drawing class` just accepts pixel unit.
Pixel changes in different resolutions. So if I use pixel unit what should be width and height? 
Please tell me what to use for both designing online and converting to picture using c#.

Comment: Straight from the w3: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html Looks like cm/in ("absolute units") are unreliable. With that said, a cm is dependent on the DPI, so I'm not sure how accurate that'd be either. From my perspective, do your very best; As long as what you have on screen is consistent (relative) to what will be generated, you should be fine (+/- an acceptable range). Anyways, I doubt to-the-pixel design is necessary.

Comment: Do not save as jpg as this will make the small fonts look awful. Use png instead. @Brad: _Straight from the w3_ Look again! It clearly states that mm and other absolute uinits are recommended for print output, which is where the results end up.

Comment: What make you think that you can only draw in pixels? If you use the Graphics object class you can set its PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter..

Comment: @TaW: User is referring to using absolute units on a webpage, which isn't print. Check your media types.

Comment: no, he wants to create business cards. the webpage is just the medium (pun intended), the aim is a printed card. and what user would want to deal with pixels?? so, both ui and goal are for mm, imo

Comment: Yes webpage is just for designing and aim is printing business card.

Comment: When I use `GraphicsUnit.Millimeter` I don't get right result. The reult picture is smaller. Is it possible making me an example?

Comment: The resulting iage or the printed output? You need to set the dpi as well. I don't do asp, but maybe you can post the graphics code? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560319/generate-staff-card/28580657?s=1|6.7854#28580657) for a pure winforms example of a staff card!

Comment: The resulted Image is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the cm values to pixel values and use it in your web application. Pixel is the best when it comes to do with the web