# How many spaces does \t use in c#

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I am building a report using StringBuilder and the details of it to be properly intended and aligned
for which i will be using

```
private static int paperWidth = 55; //it defines the size of paper
private static readonly string singleLine = string.Empty.PadLeft(paperWidth, '-');
StringBuilder reportLayout;
reportLayout.AppendLine("\t" + "Store Name");
```

I want **Store Name** in center and many such more feilds by use of **\t**
Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT** 
I want to print like. Store Name in center

Comment: \t is not translated into spaces in c# it is \t nothing else

Comment: `tab` is so 90's.  What is the font? If it's NOT fixed width then `TAB` is useless.  What is the unit of `55` paper width;.

Answer (score 2):

> If you're simulating what tabs look like at a terminal you should
>   stick with `8 spaces per tab`. A Tab character shifts over to the next
>   tab stop. By default, there is one every 8 spaces. But in most shells
>   you can easily edit it to be whatever number of spaces you want

You can realize this through the following Code:

```
  string tab = "\t";
  string space = new string(' ', 8);
  StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
  str.AppendLine(tab + "A");
  str.AppendLine(space + "B");
  string outPut = str.ToString(); // will give two lines of equal length
  int lengthOfOP = outPut.Length; //will give you 15
```

> From the above example we can say that **in `.Net` the length of `\t` is
>   calculated as `1`**

Comment: This is a rather convoluted way of arriving at the (obvious) answer of "1".  Tab is a character; ONE character.  "\t".Length yields 1 ("\tA".Length yields 2).  As @Taw points out, it is the interpretation at time of rendering that is of importance here, not the number of characters in the string.  Here is some code to produce visible results in a given rendering: <see next comment>

Comment: `System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
`
`sb.AppendLine("         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8");
`
`sb.AppendLine("12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890");
`
`sb.AppendLine("\tA\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF");
`
`Debug.Print(sb.ToString());
`
`Trace.Write(sb.ToString());
`

Answer (score 1):

A `Tab` is a `Tab` and its meaning is created by the application that renders it.

Think of a word processor where a `Tab` means:

> Go to the next tab stop.

**You** can **define** the tab stops!

To **center** output do not use `Tabs`, use the correct `StringFormat`  :

```
StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat() 
 { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
```

This centers the text inside a rectanlge in both directions:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(someText, someFont, someBrush, layoutRectangle, fmt);
```

or something like it..

But it looks as if you want to embed the centering inside a text.

This will only work if you really know everything about the output process, i.e. the device, the Font and Size as well as the margins etc..

So it will probably not be reliable at all, no matter what you do.

The best alternative may be to either give up on plain text or use a fixed number of spaces to 'mean' 'centered' and then watch for this number when you render.

If you don't have control over the rendering, it will not work.

Comment: Really helpful information @TaW I am using now padleft and padright to adjust the text to be printed

Comment: These are helpful methods indeed; but do also have a look at the [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. The example at the bottom looks interesting for aligning although not necessarily for centering.. And of course it will only work with monospaced fonts..