# Draw text centered in a ellipse/circle in winforms application

Tags: c#, graphics

Maybe a easy question but how can i draw text centered in a ellipse.
I know i can use drawstring but I don't know how to use it in combination with a Ellipse

The only way i could find is in a retangle but i need to have it in a circle/ellipse.

Momentally i have this but it doesn't work in the way i would have.

```
public void Draw(Graphics g)
{
    g.DrawString(naam, font, brush, xypos);
    g.DrawEllipse(blackPen, xpos, ypos, 100, 100);
}
```

Here is something i already tried but it doesnt work

Comment: To center output  use the correct StringFormat :

StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat() 
 { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };

This centers the text inside a rectanlge in both directions:

e.Graphics.DrawString(someText, someFont, someBrush, layoutRectangle, fmt);  -  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880669/how-many-spaces-does-t-use-in-c-sharp/32892371#32892371)

Comment: Actually filling the circle is not supported. You would either have to patch it together line by line or compromise on a smaller rectangle inside the circle.. But with such a tiny circle I guess that's not what oyu want anyway..

Comment: Thank you now i have found a solution with the following code :  RectangleF rectangle = new RectangleF(xpos, ypos, 95, 95);
            g.DrawEllipse(blackPen, xpos, ypos, 100, 100);
            StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat()
            { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
            g.DrawString(naam, font, brush, rectangle , fmt);

Comment: Duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880669/how-many-spaces-does-t-use-in-c-sharp/32892371#32892371)

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've been working in an e-mail client in which I wanted to show the 'From' name in a nice circle, this is what I got:

[image]

To do so I faced a few problems:

- Drawing the circle in a PictureBox.
- Get the drawn circle with Antialiased edges.
- Draw the Text inside
- Return the whole thing as an image, to avoid flickering.

Here is my solution:  (Comments are in Spanish, sorry about that)

```
    /// <summary>Dibuja un Circulo de Color con Texto Centrado que puede usarse como 'Logo' del Usuario.</summary>
    /// <param name="PicSize">Tamaño (pixeles) de la Imagen a Retornar</param>
    /// <param name="Brush">Color y Estilo del Circulo</param>
    /// <param name="Texto">Texto a escribir dentro del Circulo</param>
    /// <param name="Fuente">Fuente del Texto</param>
    /// <param name="BackColor">Color del Fondo y del Texto</param>
    /// <returns>Devuelve una Imagen con todos los elementos dibujados dentro.</returns>
    public static System.Drawing.Image DrawUserCircle(System.Drawing.Size PicSize, System.Drawing.Brush Brush, string Texto, System.Drawing.Font Fuente, System.Drawing.Color BackColor)
    {
        //Imagen Virtual sobre la que se dibuja y se retorna al final:
        System.Drawing.Image Canvas = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(PicSize.Width, PicSize.Height);
        System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(Canvas);

        //Tamaño del Circulo (rect):
        System.Drawing.Rectangle outerRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(-1, -1, Canvas.Width + 1, Canvas.Height + 1);
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = System.Drawing.Rectangle.Inflate(outerRect, -2, -2);

        //Todas las opciones en Alta Calidad:
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
        g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        using (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath())
        {
            //Fondo del Picture:
            g.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(BackColor),
                new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, PicSize.Width, PicSize.Height));

            //Dibuja el Circulo:
            path.AddEllipse(rect);
            g.FillPath(Brush, path);

            System.Drawing.SizeF stringSize = g.MeasureString(Texto, Fuente); //<- Obtiene el tamaño del Texto en pixeles                                                                                 
            int posX = Convert.ToInt32((PicSize.Width - stringSize.Width) / 2); //<- Calcula la posicion para centrar el Texto
            int posY = Convert.ToInt32((PicSize.Height - stringSize.Height) / 2);

            // Dibuja el Texto:
            g.DrawString(Texto, Fuente, new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(BackColor), new System.Drawing.Point(posX, posY));
        }
        return Canvas;
    }
```

Usage:

```
 System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush brush = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(
                this.picUser.ClientRectangle, System.Drawing.Color.LightSkyBlue, System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue, 70);

using (System.Drawing.Font myFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 28, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold))
                this.picUser.Image = DrawUserCircle(new System.Drawing.Size(64, 64), brush, "JC", myFont, System.Drawing.Color.White);
```

Now about your question on how to draw text centred in a Circle:

1. Measure the Text Size with the 'MeasureString' method from the Graphics object.
2. Subtract the Text Size from the Circle Size and divide that by 2 so you get the position on which you can draw the Text Centered.

All that is done in the method above, hope it helps.
Regards.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know you helped me out big time! This was exactly what i needed and i managed to customize it to my own needs. +1