# Drawing a text in the middle of an ellipse

Tags: c#, winforms, drawstring

I have an application which at some point draws many circles on a `Panel` control. Then I want to name each circle (just a letter and a number). And I want the text to be centered, to make it look nice. For now, I have something like this:

[image]

What I do, is I take the center of that circle, and do the following:

```
Graphics.DrawString($"s{i+1}", panel.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.White), pointOnCircle.X, pointOnCircle.Y);
```

(the `pointOnCircle.X and Y` being the coordinates of the center). And as you can see, it looks kinda bad.

My question here would be: Is there a way to somehow calculate that X and Y for a specified font size and those small circles radius, to make it look centered?

The result from using the accepted answer or @Johnny Mopp comment:

[image]

Comment: [How to: Align Drawn Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-align-drawn-text)

Comment: Do __not__ measure or calculate anything. The __system__ will do a better job: Simply use [centered stringformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880669/how-many-spaces-does-t-use-in-c-sharp/32892371#32892371) and draw into the very same rectangle you used for the ellipse.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, you should put that as an answer, not a comment! Great advice, did the job 100%! Edited the question with the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an overload of the `DrawString` method [that takes a `StringFormat` argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawString_System_String_System_Drawing_Font_System_Drawing_Brush_System_Single_System_Single_System_Drawing_StringFormat_) and then use the [`StringFormat.Alignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat.alignment?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_StringFormat_Alignment) and [`StringFormat.LineAlignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat.linealignment?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_StringFormat_LineAlignment) to align the string in the center and the middle of the circle:

```
using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
{
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    Graphics.DrawString($"s{i + 1}", panel.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.White),
                        pointOnCircle.X, pointOnCircle.Y, sf);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Graphics.MeasureString` to get the size (X and Y) of a string for a specified font.  You can use the resulting size to center your text.