# C# rectangle not printing as expected

Tags: c#, printing, rectangles

I have code that prints a till receipt which includes users string, the string is not fixed the user can type more or even less, thus i am not sure about the length of string user will type, i have made a rectangle to print the users string and the height will be the amount of letters in the string, it works but when the string has more characters the receipt has a big white gap before it prints the string so basically not the right way. also as the string changes, becomes short the rectangle position changes and distorts everything.

[THIS IS LINK OF THE IMAGE HOW ITS PRINTED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMR8I.jpg)

this is the code that prints the rectangle:

```
        graphics.DrawString("CONDITIONS OF SALE", bold2, Brushes.Black, 70, 60 + offX);

         //THIS IS WHERE THE RECTANGLE IS PRINTED


        Graphics pe = e.Graphics;

        float aa = pe.MeasureString(SALE, regular, 0, StringFormat.GenericTypographic).Width + 40;

        Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(SALE, regular);


        var r = new Rectangle(2, textSize.Height + 130, 275, textSize.Height + offX);
       //THIS IS THE RECTANGLE WHICH IS USED TO PRINT THE STRING WHICH IS CALLED SALE


        StringFormat s = new StringFormat();
        s.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
        drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        drawFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;


        e.Graphics.DrawString(SALE + "[ " + COUNT.ToString() + " ]", regular, Brushes.Black, r, drawFormat);  //PRINTS THE STRING CALLED SALE.//THIS IS THE PROBLEM
       e.HasMorePages = false;


        regular.Dispose();
        bold.Dispose();
```

Comment: TextRenderer is notorious for giving wrong values when measuring a string. Try to use GraphicsPath instead it will more accurately give a measurement. Alternatively (and more costly) you can render the text into a white bitmap, then measure the max bounding box (black pixel top left to black pixel bottom right) to get the size.

Comment: @RasmusSøborg i have no idea how to go about doing that can you give me an example

Comment: TextRenderer is not for printing but for rendering controls. Also: Do use the overload of MeasureString that takes and returns a SizeF ! Also a Stringformat! [Printing  example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560319/generate-staff-card/28580657#28580657)

Comment: @abru I am in a bit of a time hurry. If nobody has answered when I am home I can show u how to do it :)

Comment: @TaW i have seen the example and there they already know the size of the rectangle where as for me i dont have an idea how big the rectangle will be and rectangle accepts int digits only.

Comment: The usual way is to know the width and to let the system measure the height necessary to fit the text in with a given font.. You can pass in a large (tall) rectangle and only care for the resulting height needed or you can feed in a smaller rect and use an overload that tells you how much has fit in..

Comment: The two images have different printing contents! The first image has `Total` and `Vat` lines, the second doesn't. The second has a `Conditions of Sale` line, the first doesn't. That what produces that gap. Calculating the locations and sizes routine should take into account these differences.

Comment: @JQSOFT i have erased the total and vat lines to write out the problem in red, the *conditions of sale* is there but its distorted because it is covered by the rectangle which goes up if the string is short. thats the problem.

Comment: @RasmusSøborg any luck, still struggling?